# How do I deploy Rails to both Heroku and EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2

I would like to use Heroku for staging and EC2 for production. The [Heroku Rails setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) says to remove the `username:` from `database.yml`. That is going to break EC2, right?.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should configure your EC2 instance to have a valid `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that points to your database, so your Rails app always picks up it's connection from the environment.

- http://12factor.net

Specifically :

- http://12factor.net/config